# How to get the fields and it values on Json with c# and json.net framework?

Tags: c#, json, xamarin

I have this code:

```
var json = Newtonsoft.Json.Linq.JObject.Parse("{items:"+response.Content+"}");

Console.WriteLine(json.Count);

var items = (JArray)json["items"];

for (int i = 0; i < items.Count; i++) {

Console.WriteLine("ae");

Console.WriteLine((JObject)items[i]);

}
```

Here is the response.Content i have:

```
[{"IdUva":36,"Uva":"TESTES","IdPais":249,"Pais":"Australia","IdProduto":5114,"Descricao":"ABEL PINCHARD COTES DU RHONE","Estoque":-467700.801,"idVinhoDetalhes":84,"Produtor":"TEST","Regiao":"TESTE","Tipo":"BRANCO","Safra":"2011","Teor":99.00,"FichaTecnica":"FHGFGHFFJHFJFJHGFJFJHF","Servico":"FRANGO","Mapa":"Koala.jpg","Foto":"Chrysanthemum.jpg","Preco":1.00,"CodigoPais":36,"Bandeira":"Australia.png"}]
```

I need a way to like add each of the fields that i have in each object in a database.
For example i need to say like var wineId = (JObject)items[i].WineID;
I need to get the values of the fields that i want... how can i do that?

Answer (score 1):

Personally, I find creating objects for the data a lot easier than working with the `JObject`/`JArray` objects. So, for instance your JSON would translate in to something like:

```
public class Item
{
    public int IdUva { get; set; }
    public string Uva { get; set; }
    public int IdPais { get; set; }
    public string Pais { get; set; }
    public int IdProduto { get; set; }
    public string Descricao { get; set; }
    public double Estoque { get; set; }
    public int idVinhoDetalhes { get; set; }
    public string Produtor { get; set; }
    public string Regiao { get; set; }
    public string Tipo { get; set; }
    public string Safra { get; set; }
    public double Teor { get; set; }
    public string FichaTecnica { get; set; }
    public string Servico { get; set; }
    public string Mapa { get; set; }
    public string Foto { get; set; }
    public double Preco { get; set; }
    public int CodigoPais { get; set; }
    public string Bandeira { get; set; }
}

public class RootObject
{
    public List<Item> items { get; set; }
}
```

Then we can deserialize it:

```
RootObject json = Newtonsoft.Json.JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(
    "{\"items\":" + response.Content + "}"
);

// iterate over the items
foreach (Item item in json.items)
{
    // do what you want with them
    Console.WriteLine(item.Pais);
}
```

Of course, if you already have an "Item" object (from your database) you can use that and make things super easy. And if the properties in the JSOn don't completely align with the properties of your model, you can decorate them using [`JsonProperty`](http://james.newtonking.com/json/help/index.html?topic=html/T_Newtonsoft_Json_JsonPropertyAttribute.htm) attribute. For example, I may have an English model:

```
public class Item
{
    [JsonProperty("IdUva")]
    public int GrapeID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Uva")]
    public string Grape { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IdPais")]
    public int ParentID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Pais")]
    public string Parent { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("IdProduto")]
    public int ProductID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Descricao")]
    public string Description { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Estoque")]
    public double Stock { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("idVinhoDetalhes")]
    public int WineDetailID { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Produtor")]
    public string Producer { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Regiao")]
    public string Region { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Tipo")]
    public string Type { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("Safra")]
    public string Harvest { get; set; }

    /* etc */
}
```

And for a protip, you can generate your models using [json2csharp](http://json2csharp.com/).

Answer (score 1):

You can refer to each element of your array by its index or its key

```
var val = items[0].Value;
// or
var val = items["IdUva"].Value;
```